# How do I change universal zip file name using sbt-native-packager

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am using:

- scala 2.10.3
- sbt 13.2

with plugin:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "0.7.3")
```

I am using the `universal:packgeBin` to generate the universal zip file and publish to ivy repository.
I'd like to change the zip file name from `project_id_scalaversion_buildVersion.zip` to `project_id_scalaversion_buildVersion_dist.zip`. How would I do that?

Comment: It's just a file. Did you try renaming the file in your Build file ? You can just use renameTo defined on `java.io.File`.

Answer (score 14):

This answer is based on version 1.0.3 that I have used, but it should apply to the latest version (1.1.5) as well.

You can name your package however you want. The only thing to do is to add the following setting to the configuration of your project:

```
Universal / packageName := s"${name.value}_${scalaVersion.value}_${version.value}_dist"
```

Comment: Thanks mate. This is perfect!

Answer (score 9):

I think you cannot change the name of the generated artifact just for the `universal:packageBin` easily.

You can change the name of the generated artifact globally, by using [`artifactName`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Artifacts.html#modifying-default-artifacts).

```
artifactName := { (sv: ScalaVersion, module: ModuleID, artifact: Artifact) =>
  artifact.name + module.revision + "_dist." + artifact.extension
}
```

This will however also modify also the name of the generated jar file, and perhaps some other names of the generated artifacts.

If you wanted to change the name only of the file generated by the `universal:packageBin` you could rename the file after it was generated. Sbt gives you utilities which make this rather easy.

```
Universal / packageBin := {
  val originalFileName = (Universal / packageBin).value
  val (base, ext) = originalFileName.baseAndExt
  val newFileName = file(originalFileName.getParent) / (base + "_dist." + ext)
  IO.move(originalFileName, newFileName)
  newFileName
}
```

Now invoking the `Universal/packageBin` should execute your new task, which will rename the file after it's created.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This did the trick for us in the project target/universal/ folder very nicely.  However, we are still having the issue when truing to publish to ivy.  Any idea as to how may resolve that plz?  Thank you in advanced, Kayvan

Comment: @user111724 actually when I think of it, do you care of the name of the *.jar or you have a jar at all. Maybe the simplest working option would be just to use the `version` key. E.g. `version := "0.1_dist"`? Similarly to how `"0.1-SNAPSHOT"` works.

Comment: this worked for us. than  you so much for your help :)