# SBT dist fails to update jar name with new app version

Tags: playframework, sbt, production-environment

I am trying to change the jar name of an application packaged with `sbt dist`. However, even after updating the application version from `0.1.0-SNAPSHOT` to `0.1.0`, the jar name always results in `0.1.0-SNAPSHOT`.

**SBT version:** 1.1.1

**Play version:** 2.6.10

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out. This can be done by adding this as a setting in your *build.sbt*. Would be really useful if it had been included in the documentation https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Deploying#using-the-dist-task.

```
 .settings(packageName in Universal := s"${name.value}-$appVersion")
```

References: [How do I change universal zip file name using sbt-native-packager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899453/how-do-i-change-universal-zip-file-name-using-sbt-native-packager)